# how can i echo two different record from mysql inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to echo out two different column inside a `while loop` and the output will be inside `<td>`

here is my code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)){
    $doc_number = $row['doc_number'];
    $place_of_issue = $row['place_of_issue'];
    $crew_rank_code = $row['crew_rank_code'];
    $full_name = $row['full_name'];
    $date_of_birth = $row['date_of_birth'];
    $place_of_birth = $row['place_of_birth'];
    $date_issue = $row['date_issue'];
    $date_expiry = $row['date_expiry'];
    $place_of_birth = $row['place_of_birth'];
    echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>$crew_rank_code</td>";
        echo "<td>$full_name</td>";
        echo "<td>$date_of_birth</td>";
        echo "<td>$place_of_birth</td>";
        echo "<td>". (($row['doc_type'] == '1') ? "$doc_number" : "") . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". (($row['doc_type'] == '1') ? "$date_issue" : "") . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". (($row['doc_type'] == '1') ? "$date_expiry" : "") . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". (($row['doc_type'] == '1') ? "$place_of_issue" : "") . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". (($row['doc_type'] == '2') ? "$doc_number" : "") . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". (($row['doc_type'] == '2') ? "$date_issue" : "") . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". (($row['doc_type'] == '2') ? "$date_expiry" : "") . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". (($row['doc_type'] == '2') ? "$place_of_issue" : "") . "</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

right now, the code gives me an output up to `PASSPORT PLACE ISSUE` column but after that, my code `echo "<td>". (($row['doc_type'] == '2') ? "$doc_number" : "") . "</td>";` is no longer working

how can I make the `echo "<td>". (($row['doc_type'] == '2') ? "$doc_number" : "") . "</td>";` working?

thank in advance guys

EDIT:

i added `mysql`

```
$stmt = mysql_query("select * from info join crew_documents_table on info.id = crew_documents_table.document_crew_id join crew_rank on info.crew_rank = crew_rank.crew_rank_id where crew_rank in ('1','2','3') and crew_status = '$crew_status' and vessel = '$vessel_name' and date_issue in (select max( date_issue ) from crew_documents_table where crew_documents_table.document_crew_id = info.id)")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: working with details in `mysql_*`? I'd highly suggest moving to a less depreciated (and removed) driver API like `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Also, unless the result of the query inside the row `doc_type` contains `2` it will not output anything. Have you tried to debug and `echo` the `doc_type`?

Comment: yes. thank i know that btw.

Answer (score 0):

edit: Sorry my last answer was wrong, you should maybe rewrite your sql to end up with something like this

```
echo "<td>". $row['doc_type'][1]['$doc_number'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: in this case, the `$row['doc_type'] == '1')` is for the first column only and the `$row['doc_type'] == '2')` is for second column.

also what is inside the `$row['doc_type']` is informations of documents from another table

Comment: So maybe first fetch all your data into an array like `$fetched[$row['doctype']][ $row['doc_number']]`, `$fetched[$row['doctype']][$row['date_issue']]` and so on and then loop into it

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operators do not necessarily need `()` braces, just a first note on your readability of code. Moving on, have you yet debugged what the row `doc_type` actually contains by doing a simple output of its content? Your condition:

```
echo '<td>' . (int)$row['doc_type'] == 2 ? $doc_number : '' . '</td>';
```

Will only return the `$doc_number`, aka. `$row['doc_number']`, if the `doc_type` is set as *2*. Also, for this, always check numerical values as data-type *int*. It will automatically parse the `doc_type` in the condition with the delimiter `(int)`.

Ternary expressions are brilliant, but in your case, you're pro-longing it. For readability you could simply use conditional expressions and short-hand operators to output:

```
<?php
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)):

    $doc_number = $r['doc_number'];
    /* [...] */

    if( (int) $r['doc_type'] == 1 ): ?>

        <td> <?= $doc_number ?> </td>
        <!-- [...] -->

<?php else if( (int)$r['doc_type'] == 2 ): ?>

        <td> <?= $doc_XXXX ?> </td>
        <!-- [...] -->

<?php else:

        // debug console to check what `doc_type` value was if no condition was met
        echo '<script>console.log("[DOC_TYPE_DEBUG] ' . $r['doc_type'] . '");</script>';

    endif;
endwhile;
```